# SharePoint reporting and permissions management software

Tags: permissions, reporting

We're currently using SpDocKit for managing SharePoint permissions and doing reporting on who has access to what site/list.

Unfortunately SpDocKit does not support the ability to export the e-mail address of the user along with the rest of it's report, which is how we keep track of which user is from which client based on their e-mail domain.

Looking for suggestions on SharePoint 2010 software that can clone user permissions (we use SharePoint groups instead of AD groups), as well as produce reports on who has access to what while including their e-mail address in the report. Ideally if we could select users to report on based on e-mail address, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My name is Toni, and I am the product manager for [SPDocKit](https://www.spdockit.com). You are correct and we currently (Feb 2016), do not have such a feature. But this is something that is on our roadmap and this particular feature is scheduled to be released in Jun 2016.

There are of course many other products that can help you with permission management and reporting. You can check many alternatives over at [SharePoint Reviews](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/). These products are scattered under different categories like [Administration](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/sharepoint-administration/sharepoint-administration-products) and [Security](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/sharepoint-administration/sharepoint-security).

Answer (score 0):

I use ControlPoint by Metalogix.  No affiliation disclosures required.  I can get a report on domain\username, but not email.  Also, I can clone users and more.  This software might be overkill for your needs, but it makes our farms manageable for one admin.